# Rails webhook authentication HMAC-SHA256

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, webhooks

API client can optionally sign the callback events it sends to my webhook endpoint by including a signature in each event's HTTP header. I need to authenticate payload being sent to my webhook receiver endpoint by HMAC-SHA256.

The instructions are:

```
Your web application should verify the call-back is from NorthRow:

 1. Extract the signature value from the header
 2. Decode the value from base64 to a hex string
 3. Determine the expected signature by computing an HMAC with the
    HMAC-SHA256 hash function. Use the shared secret and the JSON
    payload from the call-back as the message (i.e. the request body).
 4. Compare the signature in the header to the expected signature.
 5. Respond with the appropriate HTTP status code
```

To meet all conditions I prepared below helper:

```
  def verify_webhook(data, hmac_header)
    digest = OpenSSL::Digest.new('sha256')
    calculated_hmac = Base64.encode64(OpenSSL::HMAC.digest(digest, SHARED_SECRET, data)).strip

    ActiveSupport::SecurityUtils.secure_compare(calculated_hmac, hmac_header)
  end
```

Does my implementation meet conditions 2 and 3? I don't think I decoded value from base64 to a hex string.

I can't compare my results with real callbacks signature (some legal issues) so I have to operate in the dark.

Comment: There's no `Base64.decode64` in there, so unless you're doing that elsewhere, it's safe to assume you're not decoding.

Comment: @meagar nope, every line of my code to verify_webhook is here. But why then in point 2 they pointed out that `2. Decode the value from base64 to a hex string` ? source: https://apidocs.northrow.com/?ruby#northrow-callback-function